# Vue composable scoping issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-composition-api

We're using Vue 2 with the Vue Composition API and we're trying to create a composable that will expose application preferences:

```js
// useApplicationPreferences.ts
import { ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useSetDarkModeMutation, useViewerQuery } from 'src/graphql/generated/operations'

const darkMode = ref(false) // global scope

export const useApplicationPreferences = () => {
  const { mutate: darkModeMutation } = useSetDarkModeMutation(() => ({
    variables: {
      darkMode: darkMode.value,
    },
  }))

  watch(darkMode, async (newDarkMode) => {
    console.log('darkMode: ', newDarkMode)
    await darkModeMutation()
  })

  return { darkMode }
}
```

This code works fine but when the composable is used in two components that are rendered at the same time we can see that `watch` has been triggered twice. This is easily solved by moving the `watch` function to the global scope (outside the function).

However, the issue then is that we can't use the `darkModeMutation`. This graphql mutation can not be moved to the global scope outside of the function, if we do that the page doesn't even get rendered.

The goal is to have `darkMode` available in many places and when the value of the `darkMode` ref changes the mutation is only triggered once. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How about exporting `darkMode` and calling `useApplicationPreferences` once, somewhere? Or, since the ref is supposed to be a singleton, might as well pass it down from the root component and use it as argument for this composable function.

Comment: The whole idea of using a composable function is to be able to reuse it in many places. On a side note, there are many `ref` objects, not just one like in the example.

Comment: Yep, got your point. But with singletons like those scattered in different places (as opposed to a centralized source), it will get harder to maintain as you scale. Besides, I don't see anything in this function that's supposed to be composable -- the duplicate watches is telling you this isnt the right pattern.

Comment: I understand. But we need to load the app preferences in `MainLayout.vue` and in `Settings.vue`. We might even have a `Statusbar.vue` where we need the same `ref` like `DarkMode`, `language`, ... A centralized composable seems like a great idea.

Comment: I still would prefer [dependency injection](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#dependency-injection) for this particular use case though. Vuetify seems to also use pretty much the same approach internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by creating a callable function that starts `watch` only when required (i.e. only once somewhere in the app).

```js
// useApplicationPreferences.ts
import { ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useSetDarkModeMutation, useViewerQuery } from 'src/graphql/generated/operations'

const darkMode = ref(false) // global scope

export const useApplicationPreferences = () => {
  const { mutate: darkModeMutation } = useSetDarkModeMutation(() => ({
    variables: {
      darkMode: darkMode.value,
    },
  }))

  const startWatch = () => {
    watch(darkMode, async (newDarkMode) => {
      await darkModeMutation()
    })
  }
  return { darkMode, startWatch }
}
```

Which the can be called once in `MainLayout.vue`:

```js
// MainLayout.vue
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useApplicationPreferences } from 'useApplicationPreferences'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { startWatch } = useApplicationPreferences()
    startWatch()
  },
})
```

All other components can then simply consume (get/set) the `darkMode` ref as required while `watch` is only running once.

```js
// Settings.vue
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useApplicationPreferences } from 'useApplicationPreferences'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { darkMode } = useApplicationPreferences()

    return { darkMode }
  },
})
```